# problem showing pictures stored outside web root folder

Tags: php, image

On a website users can upload pictures. For security reasons these are stored outside the webroot (public_html) folder. When I need to display the picture, I send the headers and have "readfile" read and output the picture data, like so:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0"); // set expiration time
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

header('Content-type: image/jpg');
header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);

readfile($path_url . '/' . $photo);
```

This works great, but the site is growing and this is starting to be a burden on the server.

Question: is there a way to send the picture or picture data to the user, without the server first having to load the picture (obviously with the picture still being stored outside the webroot folder)?

Thanks!

David

Comment: Can you define "burden" in numbers please?

Comment: I'm curious... what security reasons? Are there photos that certain users aren't allowed to view? Otherwise, if all images are publicly viewable... I'm not quite sure what benefit this has.

Comment: @col. scrapnel, I don't have hard numbers I'm afraid. But there are memory issues, server is getting slow, and "Excessive resource usage" messages.

Comment: @mark, It's a site where users can 'design' their own product with pictures of their own. Since the pictures are private, they should remain so ;-), but since the users need to the design the product they need to be able to see them (not the rest of the world).

Comment: Why not use `Cache-Control: private` (and forget `Expires`/`pragma`)? That would at least reduce your burden due to lack of caching.

Answer (score 1):

If your problems really come from this very place and you can't use HTTP caching, there is a solution, a proxy webserver. nginx with X-Accel-Redirect or lighttpd with X-Sendfile headers

Answer (score 0):

Could you store the pictures in a SQL database?

Comment: I suppose I could, but currently there is over 1GB of pictures files, and mysql is pretty burdened as well. Would this really be an improvement?

Comment: It's unlikely that would make things faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into mod_xsendfile, an apache module that can sometimes be helpful in situations like yours. Otherwise, you may need to look into implementing a dedicated media server.

Comment: Thank you as well webbiedave, i'll have a look at your solution as well.